# exports certificate of signing key to .pem extension in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, signing, code-signing-certificate

I need to change the signing key of my published app on Google Play, so I need to export the certificate of the new app signature from .jks extension to .pem, but I can not and will not need it to send the key exchange request for Google. Could someone help me ...

Comment: You can do that via complex command-line commands or simply use [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org/). Open the JKS file view the certificate and let it display as PEM file.

Answer (score 21):

You can export the certificate of your new app signature from .jks file in two way:

- Via CMD/PowerShell or Terminal :
  `keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks`
- using Key Store Explorer software (download from here : http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html) and to know how to export in .pem format using this software see this 1:09 minute video in the following link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VsYakH3OUE

Comment: In command line tools , i want to make sure that "alias" refers to MY_KEY_ALIAS and "keystore.jks" refers to OUR_OWN_KEY_NAME.jks

Comment: anyhow the command given by google is not working, the syntax changed perhaps.

Comment: this solution is really awesome it worked for me thanks.